# How to nest different Vue views?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently working on a small multipage project with Vue. I'm kind of new to Vue and JS in general, so far I got everything to work but right now im struggling to nest multiple view within each other. I've got two main views, one for my homepage and one for subpages.

I created both views and they work fine, but now I want to create multiple subsites for the subpage-view but I don't want to import my navigation component on every single sub page but I don't know how to use the subpage-view as my base and sort of "extend" it with my other views. I'm sorry if this sounds confusing, english is not my first language and I'm not really familiar with the JS vocabulary to articulate myself correctly.

My guess would be that I need to use some sort of router-view with a different name, but as I said, I don't really know if thats the right approach to this. I'm not quite sure if my approach to include multiple subsites is the right way either, my directory structure looks like this:

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSG2Q.png)

As I said, I want to include every file in "pages" into GuidePage.vue as its template, I hope someone can help me out right here

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need named views
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html